# How to open a toolbar menu by Keyboard short-cuts?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar

I have a blank toolbar button on my form and I am adding all its menus and menu items at run-time.
I need to add a keyboard shortcut to the menus of this toolbar. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you create Alt shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625820/how-can-you-create-alt-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "&" special symbol in menu item text to mark key. Have a look on this simple example:   http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Addshortcutkeytoamenuitem.htm

**EDIT:**

1) If drop down button has a text in it it's enough to set '&' symbol, like for menus to make it drop. So in this specific case "Actions" string assigned to that button at some point in the code, have to become "&Actions".

2) If it's only image drop down (no text visible on the button) unfortunately '&' symbol trick doesn't work. But you can do, for example, something like this. A *pseudocode*:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        toolStripDropDownButton1.ShowDropDown();
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot. this is for design time. I am adding them at run time. with a method that does stuff like :
tbrDropDownButton.Text = UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId);
tbrDropDownButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.StripClick);
toolStrip1.Items.Add(tbrDropDownButton);

Comment: This code should do it though... shouldn't it? `MenuItem miFile = mainMenu.MenuItems.Add("&File");` Wherever you're adding the menu item just make sure to add it like that, right?

Comment: @BDotA: I don't see any design stuff in code on that site. Everything is setuped form the code actually. The issue is may be, that you need to inject '&' into string recovered from UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId); at right place.

Comment: but I am not using MenuItem, I am using  'tbrDropDownButton = new ToolStripDropDownButton();' and then assigning it like my previous comment. so it is a ToolStripDropDownButton

Comment: @Tigran: yep I did that but it is not still working. it does not open it yet. is there a way I can do it in ProcessCmdKey by calling the EVENT HANDLER for it? but what event to call? 

'tbrDropDownButton.Text = UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId);
      tbrDropDownButton.ToolTipText = UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId);            
            tbrDropDownButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.StripClick);
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(tbrDropDownButton);'

Comment: @BdotA: do you use Text type buttons or Image type?

Comment: @Tigran: using both. please look at the screen shot I posted ( http://i54.tinypic.com/732xjm.png ), I need an "Alt+A" for that Action toolbar button.  Thanks

Comment: @ALL: I retried the approach of injecting "&" into the test of the toolbar, it IS working WHEN this form is NOT an MDI form, But when it is an MDI form it is NOT working. ( this is a setting in the main application, we can either show this form inside the parent form or we can show it out side of the parent form)

Comment: @BdotA: so try my second approach, but at this point set main form's KeyPreview property to TRUE, if it's not already. Or if this property was FALSE, make it TRUE and retry & symbol trick.

Comment: I wanted to thank you so much for your patience and helping me step by step. I used your last trick of .showDropDown and called it in ProcessCmdKey and seems it is working...I tried the "&" and setting PreviewKeyDown to TRUE but not sure why it was not still working in MDI mode.  much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't showing much code here on what you are doing.  I'll take a stab at it:

```
ToolStripMenuItem tsm = new ToolStripMenuItem("&Test Menu");
tsm.ShortcutKeys = ((Keys)((Keys.Control | Keys.T)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the place of `tbrDropDownButton.Text = UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId)`, use `tbrDropDownButton.Text = "&" + UCMDefinitions.GetCaption(textId)`. This will assign the first letter of the menu item as the shortcut key. If there are multiple items with the same shortcut key, the user will have to press Enter after one or more presses of the shortcut key.

Comment: I retried the approach of injecting "&" into the test of the toolbar, it IS working WHEN this form is NOT an MDI form, But when it is an MDI form it is NOT working. ( this is a setting in the main application, we can either show this form inside the parent form or we can show it out side of the parent form)

Comment: There is an option to merge menus with the parent and MDI forms. The menu you are seeing may not be coming from the form you think it is.